# Downloading files with WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I download files with WP7. Webclients DownloadFile is not allowed.

And where should I save them, they are only for a temporarily cause (xml files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    System.Uri targetUri = new System.Uri("http://www.dot.com/yourFile.zip");
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request);
```